# Find the remainder of the following using binomial theorem?

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the remainder when
 $$ 5^{5^{5^{5...}}}$$ (24 times 5 ) 
is divided by 24 using binomial theorem ?

Answer to the question is 5 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have, for an integer $k\ge 1$, the following
\begin{align*}
5^{4k+1}&=5\times(5^4)^{k}\\
&=5\times 625^{k}\\
&=5\left(24\times26+1\right)^k\\
&=5\left[(24\times26)^k+{k \choose 1}(24\times26)^{k-1}+\ldots+{k \choose k-1}(24\times26)+1\right]\\
&=5\times 24 \left[24^{k-1}\times26^k+{k \choose 1}\times 24^{k-2}\times 26^{k-1}+\ldots+{k \choose k-1}\times26\right]+5
\end{align*}
Then, $5^5$ gives remainder $1$ under division by $4$, and so for $5^{5^5}$, $\quad5^{5^{5^5}},\quad\ldots$

Also, all these numbers give remainder $5$ under division by $24$.

Answer (score 3):

$5^1=5, 5^2=25\equiv1\pmod{24}$.

So $5^{\rm odd}\equiv 5\pmod {24}$.

Now write your number as $5^x$, and check that $x$, being a power of $5$, is an odd number.

So the final answer is 5.

Comment: It is not 5^24 but it is 5^{5^{5^{5..24 times}}}

Comment: @user250085: Did you read his answer?

Comment: Think carefully. The $x$ in my answer above is 5's piled 23 times, a power of 5, hence odd.

Comment: Ok thanks but it was to be solved using binomial theorom as solved by someone else below.

Comment: @user250085: Why should you use an inferior method when there is a better way? Actually if you think carefully about it you will see that this analysis is the essential part of the method using the binomial theorem. All the extra is extra.

Comment: @user21820 this question was asked in our subjective exam and it was strictly mentioned that it has to be solved using binomial theorem. That's why i have asked it here.

Comment: Binomial theorem obscures what happens. The fact is, $5$ is an element of order $2$, in the multiplicative group mod 24. And you are raising $5$ to an odd number. (all positive powers of the integer 5,  odd or even number, iterated powers or vanilla powers, are always odd). Binomial theorem is not relevant.

Comment: @user250085: Okay two comments. First, you should have stated in the question that this problem was from your exam. When I read it it felt like some textbook or homework problem, in which case it is better to learn the real structure underlying the problem rather than to follow the instructions. Secondly, if you insist on using the binomial theorem, then you should figure out how to translate this solution directly to use that. *Mario G*'s solution is convoluted and unnecessary.